# missing 1 required positional argument AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, python-3.x

I need your help on an issue. I found several stackoverflow about this issue, but did not manage to solve this issue.
I have my register form and I would like, in AJAX to check if the username does exist or not.
I decided, for this case, to use a GET method, a dedicated view to this AJAX but I get an error: **verif_user() missing 1 required positional argument: 'username'**

First of all, I've always done POST Ajax call in PHP so I am not sure I handle GET properly. Is my code ok (secure)? And how can I fix my issue?

Thanks for your help.

jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "{% url 'membres.views.verif_user' %}",
    data: 'username='+value,
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        if(data == 'unavailable') {
            label.append(checkStartInvalid + "Ce nom d'utilisateur n'est pas disponible" + checkEnd);
        } else {
            label.append(checkValid);
        }
    }
});
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('membres.views',
    url(r'^verif-user$', 'verif_user'),
    url(r'^verif-email$', 'verif_email')
)
```

views.py

```
# AJAX Calls
def verif_user(request, username):
    if request.is_ajax() and request.method == 'GET':
        if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
            return HttpResponse("unavailable")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("available")
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Temporary 404")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `username` argument from `verif_user` function and get username from `request.GET` dictionary:

```
def verif_user(request):
    if request.is_ajax() and request.method == 'GET':
        username = request.GET['username']
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks, indeed it's working. Could you explain me why what I wrote does not work please?

Comment: `def verif_user(request, username):` means that `username` is passed via url (for example: `/verif-user/admin/`). In your ajax call you pass username via GET parameters. More detailed description of url parameters can be found in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/